# Indices of all values in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix `A`. I would like to generate the indices of all the values in this matrix.

```py
A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

The desired output should look like:

```py
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

Comment: `np.column_stack([np.r_[: A.size] // 3, np.r_[: A.size] % 3])` would also work if you want more alternatives :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```py
from itertools import product
list(product(*map(range, A.shape)))
```

This outputs:

```py
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

---

**Explanation:**

`A.shape` gives the dimensions of the array. For each dimension, we create a `range()` that generates all of the numbers between 0 and the length of a given dimension. We use `map()` to perform this for each dimension of the array. Finally, we unpack all of these ranges into the arguments of `itertools.product()` to create the Cartesian product among all these ranges.

Notably, the use of list unpacking and `map()` means that this approach can handle `ndarray`s with an arbitrary number of dimensions. At the time of posting this answer, all of the other answers cannot be immediately extended to a non-2D array.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
indices = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[i])):
        indices.append((i,j))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Heres a way of doing by using itertools combinations

```py
from itertools import combinations
sorted(set(combinations(tuple(range(A.shape[0])) * 2, 2)))
```

combinations chooses two elements from the list and pairs them, which results in duplication, so converting it to set to remove duplications and then sorting it.

Answer (score 1):

This line of list comprehension works. It probably isn't as fast as using `itertools`, but it does work.

```
[(i,j) for i in range(len(A)) for j in range(len(A[i]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` only you can take advantage of [`ndindex`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html#numpy.ndindex)

```
list(np.ndindex(A.shape))
```

or [`unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
list(zip(*np.unravel_index(np.arange(A.size), A.shape)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

*NB. The second option enables you to pass a `order='C'` (row-major) or `order='F'` (column-major) parameter to get a different order of the coordinates*

Example on `A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`

`order='C'` (default):

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

`order='F'`:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```